# Excel VBA - Most Efficient Way to Traverse Outlook Folders

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, outlook, directory

What is the most efficient way to traverse Outlook.Folders in Excel VBA? I'm somewhat new to Excel VBA and am presently using recursion to traverse folders.

The below code works but is there anything better than what I coded?

```
       Private Function RecursiveEmailItems( _
        Optional SubjectContains As String = Empty, _
        Optional FolderType As OlDefaultFolders = olFolderInbox, _
        Optional StartFolderNm As String = "", _
        Optional Folder As Outlook.Folder = Nothing, _
        Optional FolderDepth As Long = 1)
        
        Dim Filter As String           ' Stores outlook filter
        Dim Emails As Outlook.Items    ' Stores list of outlook emails
        Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem  ' Stores an email item
        Dim oTest As Object            ' Used to test email/folder item
        
        If SubjectContains <> "" Then Filter = "@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject ci_phrasematch '" _
            & SubjectContains & "'"
        
        '-- Check to see if need to initialize folder - First Run --
        If Folder Is Nothing Then
            If StartFolderNm = "" Then Set Folder = _
                Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(FolderType) _
            Else Set Folder = _
                Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(FolderType).Folders(StartFolderNm)
        End If
        
        '-- Get emails from the folder, use filter if not empty
        If Filter = "" Then Set Emails = Folder.Items Else Set Emails = Folder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        
        '-- Process all emails found --
        If Emails.Count > 0 Then Debug.Print Indent(FolderDepth, " ") & "-" & Folder.Name
        For Each oTest In Emails
            If TypeName(oTest) = "MailItem" Then
                Set Email = oTest
                Debug.Print Indent(FolderDepth, " ") & " |" & Email.Subject
            End If
        Next oTest
        
        '-- Process all subfolders --
        For Each oTest In Folder.Folders
            If TypeName(oTest) = "MAPIFolder" Then
                Call RecursiveEmailItems(SubjectContains, FolderType, StartFolderNm, oTest, FolderDepth + 1)
            End If
        Next oTest
    End Function
    
    Private Function GetEmailStatus()
        'Dim Filter As String: Initialize: Filter = "Timesheet " & Format(EndDt, "mm/dd/yy")
        Dim Filter As String: Initialize: Filter = "Timesheet 06"
    
        Call RecursiveEmailItems("Timesheet 06/", olFolderInbox, "Timesheet")
    End Function
    
    Private Function Indent(Count As Long, Char As String) As String
        Dim idx As Long
        For idx = 1 To Count
            Indent = Indent + Char
        Next
    End Function
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Unless you have thousands and thousands of folders it makes no difference what you do. You can use loops **if** you know your folder depth. If you don't you use recursion. So it depends on what special knowledge you have of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the `Restrict` method for each folder is not really a good idea. Instead, you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about this method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

```
  
Public m_SearchComplete As Boolean
Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
If SearchObject.Tag = "MySearch" Then
m_SearchComplete = True
End If
End Sub


Sub TestSearchForMultipleFolders()
Dim Scope As String
Dim Filter As String
Dim MySearch As Outlook.Search
Dim MyTable As Outlook.Table
Dim nextRow As Outlook.Row
m_SearchComplete = False
'Establish scope for multiple folders
Scope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder( _
olFolderInbox).FolderPath _
& "','" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder( _
olFolderSentMail).FolderPath & "'"
'Establish filter
If Application.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled Then
Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" _
& Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch 'Office'"
Else
Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" _
& Chr(34) & " like '%Office%'"
End If
Set MySearch = Application.AdvancedSearch( _
Scope, Filter, True, "MySearch")
While m_SearchComplete <> True
DoEvents
Wend
Set MyTable = MySearch.GetTable
Do Until MyTable.EndOfTable
Set nextRow = MyTable.GetNextRow()
Debug.Print nextRow("Subject")
Loop
End Sub
```

To specify multiple folders for the `Scope` parameter, use a comma character between each folder path and enclose each folder path in single quotes. For default folders such as Inbox or Sent Items, you can use the simple folder name instead of the full folder path.

Comment: Thanks Eugene! Looking forward to having time to test this out.

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine to me. Is there a particular area you want to improve?
The only line I would remove is the `If TypeName(oTest) = "MAPIFolder" Then` line. All folders in OOM are `MAPIFolder`, so the check is superfluous, but it won't do much performance wise either way.